# metaphysics: nothing

Tags: metaphysics

how can something come from nothing when nothing is the absence of something?

does language determine the true nature of reality, i.e., if I say nothing is something does that make nothing something?

Stephen V Watson

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE. Do you think you could outline your question a little more? As it is it's a bit vague what you're going for - if you could make the philosophical element of your question clear, that would be really helpful. It reads a bit like mere wordplay as is.

Comment: I cannot.  I don't see it as mere "wordplay".  I thought my question was precise.  if you can tell me what you don't understand I will make an effort to explain.

Comment: Okay, well, here's my rough go at what I understand of your question. The first sentence is a non-sequitur to me: X being the absence of Y doesn't mean Y can't come of it, see e.g. order vs. disorder. 

As for your second question, what do you mean by determine? If I call an apple an orange it doesn't make it any more an orange... *but* I can change language so that I call apples oranges.

Comment: you're confusing reality with language ...

Comment: You asked whether language influences reality, and I sought to provide exactly the *disambiguation* between the two. How I use language doesn't change reality, unless we're discussing the reality of the language (or we're in some sociolinguistic context where we're considering how language can cause people to behave). If you want people not to confuse, in your view, reality with language, I'm not sure what you're looking for when you ask exactly how the two interact.

Comment: I think reality influences language: reality came first, ergo, language must correspond with reality or it is non sensical.

Comment: @stephenvwatson In good faith, if everyone who is commenting on your question or answering your question suggest that the question is not clear, that may suggest that what you believe is clear is not clear to others.  Language is often like that.  My critique is that you are combining something, nothing, language, and causality into one question, and your comments on the only answer suggest that you're also looking to add universe and infinity to the list.  These are substantial topics in philosophy.  Each one could receive an entire library of content dedicated to it and still come up...

Comment: ... shy of fully capturing them.  Putting them all together into a single question requires us to come to a consensus about not only every topic you bring up, but how they combine together.  This is the makings of an interesting philosophical debate that could be great fun in person, but Philosophy.SE is not the right format for such debates.  The medium is simply not designed for it.

Comment: "Reality came first" and "language must correspond with reality" self-answer your current two questions, so what's your question? We don't do "am I right" and "what do you think" kinds of "questions".

Comment: You may consider [Parmenides](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/parmenides/#SomPriTypInt) and [Nothingness](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nothingness/) as well as [Sartre's Being and Nothingness](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sartre/#Ont).

Comment: If you're talking about "reality", as per preceding comments, then you typically **can't** get something from nothing, so your implied premise asking "how can you...?" is wrong to begin with. It would violate conservation (of energy among other things). On the other hand, uncertainty allows conservation to be violated, e.g., http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103724/energy-conservation-limited-by-uncertainty-principle  Moreover, this permits particles to emerge from the vacuum, e.g.,  http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/something-from-nothing-vacuum-can-yield-flashes-of-light/

Comment: Conifold ... my question is set out above.  the response you are referring to was a later comment.  I was waiting for an answer.  I have not received a logical response from anyone.  Curious?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is a 'thing' like any other. A conceptual construction   that relates to another - something - directly. Something doesn't have to come out of nothing on average, stochastics can create the world within nothing.

Comment: how can Nothing (no thing) be something.

Comment: can anyone answer my question: can no thing be some thing (any thing)?  and if the answer is no, is there only one universe and is it finite?

Comment: @stephenvwatson if you want your question answered, take commando's advice and clarify it. You can still edit your question. You may also want to read the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: i'll take your advise.  but my question was clear.  I'm still looking for an answer.  My questions and comments are meant in good faith.  I'm looking for a logical response.

Comment: You are not wrong, a first cause for 'something' makes no rational sense. No cause for 'something' makes some sense if you remove time from the equation and don't have a linear view for the Universes progression. If the 'something'  that is made, is whatever you define the Universe, All, then you'd have to explain to me why All is a thing!

Comment: No thing and nothing are different imo. Essential (absolute) nothing stands opposite to an essential something like down stands opposed to up. https://www.amazon.co.uk/Fundamental-Wisdom-Middle-Way-Mulamadhyamakakarika/dp/0195093364 if you want a read on nothing and no thing.. (need the commentary, otherwise there are Internet copies)..

Comment: Also the axiom 'energy can neither be created nor destroyed, it can only change form', a flat local space time, the global solution to general relativity showing no thing happening within the Universe, are good reasons to believe that the Whole, when 'summed up' hits 0. Not that this sum can be performed outside of the mind, we will never have access to 'All' the data. How to define 'All' without splitting it with your language though!

Comment: You are basically stuck in Pluto's Parmenides dialogue -  is becomes isn't but isn't becomes is.

Comment: Ilya   "all" is not a thing.  "all" is an abstract and can represent all of anything.

Comment: "all" would also include that which exists, regardless of our knowing it exists ... knowledge is contextutal

Comment: "is" can never be "is not" because it is "is"

Comment: 'all'  in the context of the sum of everything is not a logical concept because it has no relational properties.. Something that no 'thing' we perceive lacks. 'Is' can become 'is not' for the conventional. My grandfather is alive now, he won't be in 30 years time likely.. 'alive' is a qualifier granted. Saying he 'is not' post death is not reasonable - just a change like any other.

Comment: If existence can be seen as essential - that there is some grain of 'self' that 'is' within things, I'd like to see it first. As it stands, the world is deeply relational (even particles in physics have 0 dimensions) and an object is only revealed with a subject's observation.

Comment: To say 'it is' 'it exists' without that observation makes sense for conventional things like the apple in my fridge (not looking at it now but still readonable), but to say that the 'sum of being' 'is', the most basic of necessities for any conceptual construction about All, takes 'is not' away from All. But All logically has All within it. As such saying 'All is' shattered the unity of All, and as such.  with the use of any positive conceptual construction at all, All is split into 'this'  and 'some other'.. But that is not the' Truth is One' that you seek methinks!  :)

Comment: Try the Tao Te Ching! It's nice.. Also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_quantum_mechanics for an interpretation of quantum mechanics that solves the EPR paradox simply, and does not have a defined notion of 'All'.. As you'd hope for a physical theory that lacks access to 'All'! (which hypothesis test can ever give you a 0% significance level?

Comment: As some philosophy book I read said roughly in the commentary - rather than a-priori defining an ontology for the world and then colouring in your perceived experience with your definition, examine your perceived experience in order to define your ontology. No positive metaphysical attribute can be logically offered about the World, 'All'.. They can be added outside of logic sure, but that's outside the scope of reason.

Comment: If a tree falls in the forest does it make a sound? 'yes' is the essentialist answer.. 'No'  is the nihilist answer, some % chance (99.9999999999999%) is the physicists answer (as they'd cut some trees down and run a hypothesis test - all you have with the scientific method).. 'does not make sense' is a better answer - without an observer can the observed be? Without the observed, can an observer be? Not a single interaction within the known world has occurred without both observer and observed, so creating concepts that can avoid one or the other presents issues as to evidence!

Comment: On a side note, this also means that even with an experience of a single interaction  you can 'know' experience for the relational construct that it is.